# Perl match regex for every line /g not working?

Tags: regex, perl

having another problem with perl and regex, sorry for being a badass perl noobie ;-)

I get the whole programm output via backticks in the variable $output.

My regex matches always just for the first appearing in the output but not for every appearance..

/g didn't work either..

```
$output = `$calling 2>>bla.txt`;

if ($output =~ m/SegmentMean .+ Likelihood: ([-+]?\d+\.?\d+)/g) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

Outputs from the Java Output is:

SegmentMean 0 Likelihood: -7.138117738068088
SegmentMean 1 Likelihood: -11.508156736772925
SegmentMean 2 Likelihood: -10.424706822552386
SegmentMean 3 Likelihood: -9.560308776447586
SegmentMean 4 Likelihood: -9.26826400149502
SegmentMean 5 Likelihood: -9.524685714290996
SegmentMean 6 Likelihood: -8.360030637461975
SegmentMean 7 Likelihood: -8.163275211919945
SegmentMean 8 Likelihood: -7.917569593466525
SegmentMean 9 Likelihood: -9.043243571260344

Up to SegmentMean 20 ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try going through the matches like an array (and use a better regex):

```
while ($output =~ m/SegmentMean \S+ Likelihood: ([-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?)/g) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

That should work.

You can even turn it into a single line:

```
print "$1\n" while ($output =~ /SegmentMean \S+ Likelihood: ([-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/g);
```

Comment: I hope it's OK I edited your post. I don't know Perl at all, so I deleted my answer and used the regex in your post. +1 :)

Comment: saw your post earlier Tim and yes it helped me! can be easy if you get the right point ;=

Comment: You should use a while() (m//g in scalar context) rather than a for() (m//g in a list context).

Comment: Cheers Tim! And good point on the while loop, tadmc, edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're only printing the first match. $1 is the first match.